# How to get Package List with Security and bugfix details?

Tags: package-management

I am new Ubuntu User and I liked it most.

In RHEL after installing yum-security package, we can get list of updates like this

```
# yum list-security
```

Sample Outputs:

```
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
RHSA-2009:1148-1 security httpd-2.2.3-22.el5_3.2.x86_64
RHSA-2009:1148-1 security httpd-devel-2.2.3-22.el5_3.2.i386
RHSA-2009:1148-1 security httpd-manual-2.2.3-22.el5_3.2.x86_64
RHSA-2009:1148-1 security mod_ssl-1:2.2.3-22.el5_3.2.x86_64
list-security done
```

Is there any command to check or list security or bugfix packages??

So I can easily install only bug fixed packages or security fixed packages.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
```

Sample output (I don't have updates on my system):

```
0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

`/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check 2>&1 | cut -d ';' -f 1`

Returns the number of pending security updates.

In case that you need to install security updates automatically, there is the package [unattended-upgrades](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unattended-upgrades)

Answer (score 1):

If you run the basic upgrade command,

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then by default you only get only security upgrades and major bug fixes. You would have to change your package sources to get upgrades to newer versions. You can run

```
sudo apt-get -s upgrade
```

to see what `apt-get upgrade` would do without actually changing anything.